# unable to center images (css)

Tags: css, image, center

```
.photospace .slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    height: 450px;
```

i have a slideshow with various image sizes but non bigger than 530 by 549. for images that are smaller, how do i enter them? pictures of what i want to do. i can add margin/padding but it forces images that are already 530x549 below the screen.

my website

Comment: it looks to me that they are working correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` and then `vertical-align:middle`.

I can see you are currently giving `.gal_content`   `display:block` with jQuery, so you will need to change this to `table-cell`

```
.photospace .gal_content{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float: right;
    width: 530px;
    height: 549px;
}
```

Comment: @user1421414 If I managed to help, you could thank by formally [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. That is quite an established (and nice, too) form of thanking here on SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

Give **line-height** same as the `height` of the DIV. Write like this:

```
    .photospace .slideshow a.advance-link {
        line-height: 549px;
        width: 530px;
    }
.photospace .slideshow img{
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: This only works if you know 100% what the height of the image will be. For example, if an image with a height of 510px is used it will not work.

Comment: @BePatient see the OP images in that he define height of the div which is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you wish to vertically align it to the center, this is not possible *(in all browsers at least)* purely with DIVS and CSS. You will need to use Javascript to position it correctly.

Alternatively if you aren't phased about older browsers have a look at the new Webkit CSS3 property called [Flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/).

Here is an example with an image thrown in an 800x800px box and auto aligned using Flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/7rFEn/embedded/result/

Comment: "If you mean you wish to vertically align it to the center, this is not possible (in all browsers at least) purely with DIVS and CSS". Ahhmmmm what? Explain please.

Comment: What I mean is using CSS you cannot align anything inside of a div to the vertical center, to do this you will need to use tables _which really shouldn't be used for this_ or use Javascript.